# Mapped 2 Json Object In NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I had 2 Json Object like :

```
const conversionMap = {
    name : "First Name"
};
```

and

```
const userObject = {
    name : "MTae"
}
```

Then what will I do in `mapped2Json(conversionMap, userObject, mappedResult)` in order to have the `mappedResult === { First Name : "MTae" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is recursive function which will map nested objects as well

https://jsbin.com/cukuxuxopi/edit?js,console

```
function mapped2Json(map, data) {
  var result = { }
  for (var key in map) {
    var value = map[key]

    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      result[key] = mapped2Json(value, data[key])
    } else {
      result[value] = data[key]
    }
  }

  return result
}


const map = {
  name: 'First Name',
  surname: 'Last name',
  birthday: {
    day: 'Day',
    month: 'Month',
    year: 'Year',
  }
}

const data = {
  name: 'Michael',
  surname: 'Gordan',
  birthday: {
    day: 13,
    month: 2,
    year: 1990,
  }
}

console.log(mapped2Json(map, data))
```